# Syncronize a graphics item with a symbol in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcade

I would like to create a graphics item, such as a rectangle, and have its fill color always synchronized to the fill color of a particular symbol class in the map, in the same way a legend patch is always synchronized to its corresponding symbol.
Is there any way to do this with ArcPy, Arcade, or any other hack?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one hack to accomplish what I needed:

In the layout, create a separate Map Frame of the shape and size desired for the graphic. Activate that map frame to zoom and center it on a polygon that you want it to match. Zoom in so far that a label can't render within that map frame. Now the map frame is a patch of color that synchronizes with a polygon fill color in the map... because it is essentially a tiny window viewing that polygon.

Limitations:
This works in the situation where the polygon fill is a flat single color, but effects like gradients won't work.